# How to convert WavPack to FLAC?

Tags: audio, conversion, flac

I need to convert a bunch of `.wv` files to `.flac` but I can't seem to find a program to do it. Does anybody know how I can do this?

P.S.: I was wondering why Audacity does not support the importing `.wv` format if it is open source and lossless. Does anybody know?

---

**Update:** Somewhere I read about converting `.ape` to `.flac` using `ffmpeg`, so I decided to try replacing the `.ape` with `.wv` and at first it seems to work but then I get this at the end:

```
[wv @ 0x8e7c200] Invalid block header.te= 836.1kbits/s    
audiofile.wv: Invalid data found when processing input
```

So my question is: what is wrong here?

By the way, the command used was `ffmpeg -i audiofile.wv audiofile.flac`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14):

The ffmpeg error you're getting makes me think you might just have a corrupted file. You could try `sox audiofile.wv audiofile.flac`. Alternatively, you could use the wavpack tools:

```
wvunpack audiofile.wv -o - | flac - -o audiofile.flac
```

Note that wiill not copy over any metadata; you'll need to do that separately.

If even the wavpack tools can't successfully read the file, then your file is probably just corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using command lines, you could use `ffmpeg`. If you simply run:

```
ffmpeg -i file.wv -acodec flac file.flac
```

(Assuming of course the file you want to convert is called "file.wv"), will produce a file called **file.flac**. Of course, if you want to, you can change that last bit of the command so that ffmpeg outputs a different filename.

Or, if you at least have the ffmpeg libraries installed, you should be able to import the wavpack files into Audacity.

Comment: OP already mentions having tried ffmpeg (though probably OP edited it in while you were writing your answer)

Comment: "Invalid data found when processing input", ffmpeg 6.0, while `wvunpack` processed it well